# Bayesian estimator and prediction

Tags: bayesian, estimation, point-estimation

For a Bayesian, if he/she can make predictions using the entire posterior, why bother to calculate a Bayes estimate like the posterior mean or MAP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: when you *need* the point estimate. For example, you are making sales forecast that would be used for ordering and allocating certain number of goods in the warehouse. In such case you cannot say that the order should follow some distribution because you *need* some numeric value for the order. Of course, since you have the posterior distribution you can make interval forecast and quantify the risk associated with the forecast, so it is actually better to have the distribution, but still you may need the point estimate.

The second reason is that MAP estimation is much more computationally efficient then, say, MCMC sampling, so using MAP may be more convenient in many cases.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose in your example $\lambda$ is the parameter. Now by integrating out $\lambda$ in the evidence term, we get the predictive posterior distribution. So do you mean the estimate is actually of the prediction rather than the estimate of $\lambda$ (which I reckon is the Bayes estimate)?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but it is true that if you have posterior distribution, then you can easily obtain point estimate from it. Your question is when do we need it if I understand you correctly. Btw, I edited the part about $\lambda$ since I made myself unclear.

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly. But in your example, ''sales' seem to be the parameter but I thought something else should be the parameter. You see, if I want to forecast sales, based on existing sales figures, I form the predictive distribution of sales (by integrate out the parameter) and from it I make an point forecast. But what about the parameter?

Comment: Imagine that you use Poisson-gamma model where sales follow Poisson distribution parametrized by $\lambda$, where you use gamma distribution for $\lambda$. Since $\lambda$ is both the parameter and mean of Poisson distribution then you will be estimating $\lambda$ to predict average sales.

Comment: Ah, if I understand correctly, as the parameter relates to the predictive posterior in some way, by getting a point estimate of the parameter, we can also get a point estimate of the predictive posterior?

Comment: Not really, you will be estimating $p(\lambda|\text{data}) \propto p(\text{data}|\lambda) p(\lambda)$, so you end up with posterior $p(\lambda|\text{data})$. In standard Bayesian estimation, this is a posterior distribution, but you can take mean of it as a point estimate. Given the past sales you predict how many items to order when the prediction is about $\lambda$ (either distribution or point estimate).

Comment: Now, back to square one then. I use the posterior to get a point estimate of $\lambda$, but there is no value in the $\lambda$ itself if it isn't related to average sales (and hence the predicitve posterior), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With MAP you end up with mode of $\lambda$ posterior, with MCMC you have whole posterior distribution, but if in the end what you need is a point estimate, then you need a point estimate.